# Body of HTTP-request as spray-json object

Tags: spray, spray-json

I want to create a simple rest-service with spray. The rest service shall receive a json-body via http put. I want to pass the parsed json-string to a function for further processing.

Is there any example out there how to do this? I have not found any example how to access the body of a http put request as a parsed json object (spray-json)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code for your reference.

```
import spray.http._
import spray.routing._

import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._

case class Person(fname: String, lname: String, age: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val PersonFormat = jsonFormat3(Person)
}

class TestActor extends HttpServiceActor {
  import MyJsonProtocol._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

  override def receive: Receive = runRoute(serviceRoute)

  private val serviceRoute = path("test_end_point") {
    put {
      entity(as[Person]) { person =>
        println(person)
        complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I tested it using following command

```
curl -X PUT  -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "fname": "Vishal", "lname" :"John", "age" : 32 }' localhost:9000/test_end_point
```

Comment: Thx John. I've missed the entity directive, since I've searched for body.